# Save array output to csv in Python

Tags: python, arrays, file, csv, save

I am trying to scrape data from a website. I am making a loop to extract the data, and store in a variable, but a can't save it in csv file. Being new to Python and BeautifulSoup I'm not getting very far. Here's the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

r = "https://sofia.businessrun.bg/en/results-2018/"
content = requests.get(r)

soup = BeautifulSoup(content.text, 'html.parser')


for i in range (1,5):
    team_name= soup.find_all(class_="column-3")
    team_time= soup.find_all(class_="column-5")


for i in range (1,5):
  print (team_name[i].text)
  print (team_time[i].text)

with open("new_file.csv","w+") as my_csv:
    csvWriter = csv.writer(my_csv,delimiter=',')
    csvWriter.writerows(team_name)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What happens when you run it? Is there an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another way of doing your **scraping** and saving it in a csv by using pandas. The code is here below:

```
import requests

# I changed this
import pandas as pd

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

r = "https://sofia.businessrun.bg/en/results-2018/"
content = requests.get(r)

soup = BeautifulSoup(content.text, 'html.parser')


for i in range (1,5):
    team_name= soup.find_all(class_="column-3")
    team_time= soup.find_all(class_="column-5")

tn_list = []
tt_list = []

# I changed this to have string in place of tags 
tn_list = [str(x) for x in team_name]
tt_list = [str(x) for x in team_time]
        
for i in range (1,5):
    print(team_name[i].text)
    print(team_time[i].text)

# I put the result in a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({"teamname" : tn_list, "teamtime" : tt_list})

# I use regex to clean your data (get rid of the html tags)
df.teamname = df.teamname.str.replace("<[^>]*>", "")
df.teamtime = df.teamtime.str.replace("<[^>]*>", "")

# The first row is actually the column name
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df.iloc[1:]

# I send it to a csv
df.to_csv(r"path\to\new_file.csv")
```

this should normally work

Comment: Works great! Thank you!